# Do Changes Made on Table Created by Joining a View and an Another Table Affect Original Table View Based On?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view, oracle12c

Suppose I have a view created on a table. If I change some record on my view, the original table is also changed too. What if I join this view with an another table and change some records on this result table I got by joining, would original table on which view based also be changed?

Comment: What DBMS are you using ..?

Comment: Oracle 12c. We're using it at work. I wonder if views can cause such a problem.

Comment: Show us an example UPDATE.

Comment: I'm just thinking on a hypothetical case. If I make a change can it affect original table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, yes, if the views are constructed in such a way that the underlying tables are updateable through the view. For example, let's say I have a table named TABLE_1 and create a view VIEW_1 as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_1 AS
  SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_1
```

If I issue the update statement

```
UPDATE VIEW_1
  SET FIELD_N = 'XYZ'
  WHERE KEY_1 = 123
```

Oracle is bright enough to pass the UPDATE through to the underlying table, and TABLE_1 will be updated.

A view of any complexity, however, will most likely contain operations that make the view non-updateable. So let's say I have the following VIEW_2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_2 AS
  SELECT KEY_1,
         FIELD_N,
         SUM(SOME_OTHER_FIELD) AS OTHER_SUM,
         MIN(YADDA_YADDA) AS MIN_YADDA
    FROM TABLE_1
    GROUP BY KEY_1,
             FIELD_N
```

an UPDATE of this view will fail with an `ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view` error. So whether you can update through a view or not very much depends on what operations the view is performing.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9ab5f06cea6cb8b1765cf473a7790a29)

Comment: Just to clarify one point in this good answer: a update can be done on views that join some tables, there are several conditions, the most important one is that the table where the updated columns are must be key-preserved by the joins. see [here] (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-views-sequences-and-synonyms.html#GUID-C37E704C-AF40-42DA-85ED-372A62A74E58) for a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question quite confusing and this is too long for a comment.

> Suppose I have a view created on a table. If I change some record on my view, the original table is also changed too.

This doesn't make much sense.  In general, you do not modify *views* but base tables.  You change the data in the *base tables* and this is reflected in the views.

What you are saying is possible using *instead of* triggers on views.  These can change the base tables -- or anything for that matter.  They are entirely under your control and really have nothing to do with Oracle functionality (other than Oracle allowing the existence of `instead of` triggers on views).

`JOIN`s are operations in `SELECT` statements, and these do not modify data.  Once again, if the data is changing that would be through *instead of* triggers, which are entirely under your control.

I think you may be confused by terminology.  If your database is behaving as your describe, then you (or someone else) has put some effort into making it behave that way.

Comment: I don't mean if  I join a view and a table it causes original table the view based on to be changed. I wanted to meant after join operation between a view and a table, for example if I delete some records of the result table would the original table the view based on be changed?

Comment: @TolgaKarahan . . . You can't "delete records from a result table".  I mean, you could save the results as a table and then delete *from that table*.  That would have nothing to do with the original data.

Comment: What if result also saved as a trigger and I delete rows from it? Is it possible?

Comment: @TolgaKarahan . . . Then you are writing the triggers and you will know what base tables are affected.